# Input Botón deja escribir

Tags: html

Estoy haciendo una página web para prácticar ya que me gusta y tengo un problemilla, tengo un mini-formulario de contacto en el footer y al clickar en enviar, me deja editar ese campo desde la web, es decir, doy click en el input que tiene puesto de texto "Enviar" y si le doy click me deja editar el "Enviar"

Os dejo el código y unos fotos de lo que me refiero

```css
    footer .contacto {
    padding: 30px 0;
}
footer .contacto h3 {
    font-size: 34px;
    line-height: 34px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #3895ea;
    text-align: center;
}
footer section .formulario {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
footer section .formulario input[type="text"], 
footer section .formulario input[type="email"], 
footer section .formulario textarea {
    border: 2px solid #cecece;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #a4a4a4;
}
footer section .formulario input[type="text"]:hover, 
footer section .formulario input[type="email"]:hover, 
footer section .formulario textarea:hover {
    border: 2px solid #3895ea;
}
footer section .formulario input[type="text"],
footer section .formulario input[type="email"] {
    width: 49%;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
footer .contacto .formulario textarea {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    min-width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100px;
    max-height: 300px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
footer .contacto .formulario .boton {
    margin: auto;
    background: #3895ea;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 15px 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 10%;
}
footer .contacto .formulario .boton:hover {
    background: #387bea;
}
```

```html
    <div class="contenedor">
                <section class="contacto" id="Contacto">
                    <h3>Contacto</h3>
                    <form action="" class="formulario">
                        <input id="nombre" type="text" placeholder="Nombre" name="nombre" required>
                        <input type="email" placeholder="Correo" name="correo" required>
                        <textarea name="mensaje" placeholder="Mensaje:" ></textarea>
                        <input type="boton" class="boton" type="submit" value="Enviar">
                    </form>
                </section>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cometes 2 errores:
Tienes puesto dos veces el atributo "type".El segundo error es que el primer type lo tienes en español, los atributos van en inglés, si acaso las clases que tengas definidas en un CSS personalizado puedes declararlas con el nombre que quieras.

Debes ponerlo asi:

```
<input type="submit" class="boton" value="Enviar">
```